# Find all the nonisomorphic complete bipartite graphs $G=(V,E)$ where $ |V|=6$

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I am confused by this question. The answer guide says that there are 3 graphs.
i) $K_{1,5}$
ii) $K_{2,4}$
iii) $K_{3,3}$.

I don't see how I can draw them to be non isomorphic.

This question is from the textbook called Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics, 5th Ed. Ralph Grimaldi (available online).

Comment: O.k., so you did already draw them, but do not really see how this shows that there are no isomorphisms between any of the three graphs, right? Do you know some property of graphs that is different in these three graphs, but for which you know that it must be preserved under isomorphisms?

Comment: what about $K_{0,6}$

Comment: @ZKe: I would also include $K_{0,6}$, but I do not know if the definition in the textbook of the OP restricts $K_{m,n}$ to $m,n>0$.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is asking for the number of ways one might separate the $|V|$ vertices into two groups $V_1$ and $V_2$ such that $|V_1|, |V_2|$ are not negative and $|V_1| + |V_2| = 6$. The solutions are $(|V_1|, |V_2|) = (1, 5), (2, 4),$ and $(3, 3)$. (We disregard $(5, 1), (4, 2)$ and the other $(3, 3)$ because the last solution is a duplicate and the first two violate the non-isomorphism constraint.